# How to update a website's information with Jquery without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a webapp that will display information and update it when a JSON file is updated. My current code only updates when both the JSON file are updated and the page is refreshed. The key is not to have the page refreshed. Here is my current code

```
<script>
            $.getJSON('package.json', function (data) {
                for (var i in data) {
                    var username = data[i].username;
                    var value = data[i].value;
                    var tokens = data[i].tokens;
                    $("#playerlist").append('<tr><td>-' + username + ' has deposited $' + value + ' in ' + tokens + ' tokens' + '</td></tr>');
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: call the getJSON after some time interval, using setInterval(),

Comment: You would want to do an `ajax` request for this.

Comment: @Dreamweaver: You mean `setInterval` (and/or `setTimeout` -- I'd use `setTimeout` and reschedule it, since otherwise you have two async processes interacting, and it gets chaotic *fast*)

Comment: I meant setInterval, as setTimeOut will be called only once..

Answer (score 1):

```
By using SetInterval we can update the UI in some timeinterval.

     function refreshContent()
        {
        $.getJSON('package.json', function (data) {
                        for (var i in data) {
                            var username = data[i].username;
                            var value = data[i].value;
                            var tokens = data[i].tokens;
                            $("#playerlist").append('<tr><td>-' + username + ' has deposited $' + value + ' in ' + tokens + ' tokens' + '</td></tr>');
                        }

                     setTimeOut(refreshContent, 1000) /// again wait for 1 sec and do refresh
                    });
        }

        setTimeOut(refreshContent, 1000) \\\this will update in every 1 sec.
```

Comment: Actually what this does is that every 1 second it appends the HTML to the website over and over again. It only needs to update it.

Comment: @NightShadows: So modify slightly as needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I just wanted to point out for everyone else that it was slightly flawed.